# SQL Server 2008: Can you have a query where you do a diff on a count from two tables and then output result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What I would like to do is produce a query which returns the difference between the sum of two other queries.  I have tried, but I have failed.  Here is what I tried:

```
Select ((SELECT COUNT(*) as B FROM Business) - (SELECT COUNT(*) as S FROM Shusiness)) as BusMinusShus
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, just put in a * in the count:

```
Select ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Business) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Shusiness)) as BusMinusShus
```

Comment: +1. I also don't see why aliases are needed here (I mean `AS B` and `AS S`)